# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable (don't know how to fix it)

Tags: python

The program is working fine, but I am receiving a `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`, and I am not sure how to fix it.

This is my code: function that reads in air quality data and returns a dictionary of average air quality

```
def make_avg_pm2_dictionary():
    d = {}
    with open("air_data.tsv", encoding ='latin1') as fd:
        for line in fd:
            row=line.strip().split("\t")
            if row[0] in d:
                key = row[0]
                val1 = float(d[row[0]])
                val2 = float(row[6])
                temp = (val1 + val2)/2
                d[key] = round(temp, 2)
            elif row[0] == 'Country':
                val1 = 0
            else:
                d[row[0]] = float(row[6])
    fd.close()
    return d
```

function that takes a dictionary of air quality for each country (aqd)
and returns a dictionary with the population and air quality for each country
if that country has air quality data

```
def add_cia_population_data(dic1):
    with open("cia_population.tsv", encoding='latin1') as fd:
        for line in fd:
            row = line.strip().split("\t")
            key = row[1]
            if key in dic1:
                temp = [row[2], dic1[key]]
                d = {key: temp}
                dic1.update(d)
        fd.close() 
    return dic1
```

print out country name, population, and pm2 values
that exceed the WHO's threshold (in ug/m3) for 1 year pm2 levels
that increase long-term mortality risk by 15% from figure 1
Print the data sorted by the last name of the country

```
def print_exceed_threshold(data,threshold):
    for keys in data:
        temp = data[keys]
        if temp[1] >= threshold:
            name = str(keys)
            mp2 = str(temp[1])
            pop = str(temp[0])
            print("{0:<25} {1:<20} {2:<10}".format(name,pop,mp2))
```

call all the functions

```
def main():

# Build dictionary from air quality file
    avg_pm2 = make_avg_pm2_dictionary()
# Read in cia population and create a dictionary
# with population and average pm2 data for each country
    country_data = add_cia_population_data(avg_pm2)
# print countries with air quality
# exceeding WHO's guidelines
    print_exceed_threshold(country_data,35)

#run the analysis


main()
```

The program should displays some statistics, nothing much.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-6bf5bffb30ed>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/felipe/Desktop/A05/A05.py', wdir='/Users/felipe/Desktop/A05')

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/felipe/Desktop/A05/A05.py", line 82, in <module>
    main()

  File "/Users/felipe/Desktop/A05/A05.py", line 77, in main
    print_exceed_threshold(country_data,35)

  File "/Users/felipe/Desktop/A05/A05.py", line 60, in print_exceed_threshold
    if temp[1] >= threshold:

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace, and tell us what line it's pointing to.

Comment: Looks like the issue is in your `print_exceed_threshold` function and probably specifically related to the structure of the `country_data` that you are passing as an argument. You should narrow your question to just those things and include a sample of what `country_data` looks like.

Comment: I am new to programming and this is my first post here, so I don't really know how to do that, but I will try.

Comment: In case it helps, you can basically delete everything in your question except the traceback and the `print_exceed_threshold` code and add in a sample of what `country_data` looks like. Chances are if you do that as well as take a look at the answer from @NipunSampath, you will solve your problem before you even complete the edit.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it the error is in the line  `if temp[1] >= threshold:` in the function `print_exceed_threshold()`. You can't call `temp[1]` if temp is not a list.

Comment: Or unless temp is a string with more than one character, or a dict where 1 is a key, etc. But your point is on target that `temp[1]` will throw an error if `temp` is not a data structure that can be accessed by an index or key value using that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In `print_exceed_threshold` function, you have a variable called `temp` that is a float and not an array. I'd rewrite the function with some breakpoints or printing:

```
def print_exceed_threshold(data, threshold):
    print(threshold, type(threshold)) // to see what this variable is
    for keys in data:
        temp = data[keys]
        print(temp, type(temp))
        # if temp[1] >= threshold:
        #     name = str(keys)
        #     mp2 = str(temp[1])
        #     pop = str(temp[0])
        #     print("{0:<25} {1:<20} {2:<10}".format(name,pop,mp2))
```

Then you'll have to go back to `add_cia_population_data` and find the row that causes your keys to be wrong. Maybe add in a print statement right before `dic1.update(d)`